# create observable<bool> from observablecollection

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I have ObservableCollection<T> and I need to create observable<bool> which returns true if collection contains any elements

I try to do this

```
var collectionHasElementsObservable =
            Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
                ev => ((ObservableCollection<MyType>)_items).CollectionChanged += ev,
                ev => ((ObservableCollection<MyType>)_items).CollectionChanged -= ev);
```

But I don't know how to convert this into IObservable<bool>

How can I create observable<bool> from this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `Select` to map the event into one of having elements:

```
        ObservableCollection<int> coll = new ObservableCollection<int>();

        var hasElements = 
        Observable.FromEventPattern<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler,NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs>(
            a => coll.CollectionChanged += a,
            a => coll.CollectionChanged -= a)
        .Select(_ => coll.Count > 0);
```

Example:

```
        hasElements.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        coll.Add(1);
        coll.Add(2);
        coll.Remove(1);
        coll.Remove(2);
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 8):

I notice you have the ReactiveUI tag - were you to be using ReactiveCollection, this would be even easier:

```
coll.CollectionCountChanged.Select(x => x > 0);
```

Comment: thanks for reactiveui. I've used this _bookmarks.ObserveCollectionChanged().Select(i => _bookmarks.Any()). I have ObservableCollection<T>